# SQL statement : average

Tags: sql, database, join

My question: What is the average age to become the first grandpa. The solution should be given out as average_age. The day a person becomes grandpa is where his first grandchild was born.

Relations:

```
human (name, gender, age) 
parent (ParentName, ChildName) -> is subset of human(name).
```

Table:

[image]
[image]

I do know that grandpa is the person which has a parentname and a child in childname which is also a person(father) in parentname which has children in childname (grandchildren). The problem is now how do I get the average age to become grandpa.

What I got so far:

```
SELECT AVG(age) as average_age
FROM human h JOIN
     parent p
     ON h.name = p.parentname
WHERE h.gender = 'm' AND p.parentname = p.childname AND h.name = p.parentname
```

Expected outcome:

```
average_age : 52
```

Comment: What do you mean by *become the* **first** *grandpa*?

Comment: @GMB Maybe it means the age at which one's _first_ grandchild is born?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: First time a father became grandpa. It just means that a grandpa can also have more grandchildren and that you have to calculate the average age when he became grandpa.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely unusually to be storing the AGE of people in a table, because that changes -- every day.  The data should be stored with a date of birth.

This is an aggregation query, but you have to join the tables multiple times.  To get grandparents, you need a join on the `parents` table.  Then you need to bring in `humans` for filtering:

```
select avg(min_age * 1.0)
from (select min(h_grandparent.age - h.grandchild.age) as min_age
      from parent p join  -- p.parentname is the grandparent
           parent pchild
           on p.childname = pchild.parentname join
           human h_grandparent
           on p.parentname = h_grandparent.name join
           human h_grandchild
           on pchild.childname = h_grandchild.name
      where h_grandparent.gender = 'm'
      group by h_grandparent.name
     ) a
```

Comment: Why do you multiply min_age with 1.0 ?

Comment: @Lyaso . . . You don't specify the database and some databases take the average of an integer as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would address this with an `exists` condition that filters on humans that have grandchilds:

```
select avg(age) avg_age_of_grandpas
from human h
where 
    gender = 'm'
    and exists (
        select 1
        from parent p1
        inner join parent p2 on p2.parentName = p1.childName
        where p1.parentName = h.name
    )
```

The `exists` condition ensures that the person has at least one child and one grand child. The the outer query computes the average of such humans. Given the information available in your table structure, this seems to me like the most logical approach. Unlike `join`s, using `exists` avoids duplicating the records (and getting wrong results in the average) when a person has more than one line of descendants.

---

If you want the age of the grand parent at the date when their first grand child was born, then it is a bit complicated. This should get you close to what you expect:

```
select avg(h.age - g.maxGrandChildAge) avg_age_of_grandpas
from human h
inner join (
    select 
        p1.parentName grandParentName, 
        max(h1.age) maxGrandChildAge
    from parent p1
    inner join parent p2 on p2.parentName = p1.childName
    inner join human h1 on h1.name = p2.childName
) g
on g.grandParentName = h.name
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the average age of 70.5 but the desired outcome should be 52.  Maybe the age of his grandchildren have a factor on his average age ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 more `join`s and subtraction the age of biggest grandchild:

```
SELECT AVG(p_age) average_age
FROM
(
    SELECT  h.name, h.age-MAX(h2.age) as p_age
    FROM parent p1 
        LEFT JOIN parent p2 ON P1.childname = P2.parentname
        INNER JOIN human h ON P1.parentname = h.name
        INNER JOIN human h2 ON P2.ChildName = h2.name
    WHERE h.gender = 'm' AND p2.childname IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY h.name, h.age
)pAges
```

Please consider that the name is not appropriate data for doing this task.